# jquery: how can I delay the each() from being triggered

Tags: jquery, delay, each

How can I delay `each()` from being triggered?

This is the code that delays each box from fading out at certain time given.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var delay = 0;
    $('.block-item:lt(16)').each(function(){ 

        //^^ do for every instance less than the 16th (starting at 0)
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({
            opacity:0
        },500);
        delay += 500;

    });


});
```

But I want to delay about five second before the `each()` is triggered. Is it feasible?

Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/QAWTy/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just a matter of delaying the initial animation, why not just start with a 5000 delay?

http://jsfiddle.net/QAWTy/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var delay = 5000;
    $('.block-item:lt(16)').each(function(){ 

        //^^ do for every instance less than the 16th (starting at 0)
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({
            opacity:0
        },500);
        delay += 500;

    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet I did specially for this purpose.
You can call iniFadeChildren($('.parent'), 'li', 500) 
And all the li in parent are gonna fade one after another

```
function iniFadeChildren(pParent, pChildrenType, pDelay, pSpeed){
    pParent.find(pChildrenType).css({display:'none'});
    if(!pChildrenType){pChildrenType='*'} if(!pDelay){pDelay=200} if(!pSpeed){pSpeed=300}
    fadeChildren(pParent, pChildrenType, pDelay, 0, pParent.children(pChildrenType).length, pSpeed);
}

function fadeChildren(pParent, pChildrenType, pDelay, pNbr, pTotal, pSpeed){
    pParent.find(pChildrenType).eq(pNbr).fadeIn(pSpeed);
    pNbr++;
    if(pNbr!=pTotal){
        var command='fadeChildren('+pParent+', '+pChildrenType+', '+pDelay+', '+pNbr+', '+pTotal+')';
        t=setTimeout(function(){fadeChildren(pParent, pChildrenType, pDelay, pNbr, pTotal, pSpeed)}, pDelay);
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone have ideas on how to improve this code, that will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.block-item:lt(16)').delay(delay).each(function(){  

        //^^ do for every instance less than the 16th (starting at 0) 
        $(this).animate({ 
            opacity:0 
        },500); 
        delay += 500; 

    }); 
)
```

Comment: This will not work.  `each` is not an animation so it will not be queued.  Therefore delay will not delay the each.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var delay = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('.block-item:lt(16)').each(function(){ 

        //^^ do for every instance less than the 16th (starting at 0)
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({
            opacity:0
        },500);
        delay += 500;

    });

   }, 5000); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean wait 5 seconds just before the initial call to each? If so use `setTimeout` [setTimeout Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QAWTy/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var delay = 0;
    // Wrap the function with setTimeout
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.block-item:lt(16)').each(function(){ 

            //^^ do for every instance less than the 16th (starting at 0)
            $(this).delay(delay).animate({
                opacity:0
            },500);
            delay += 500;
        });
    }, 5000); // 5000 = 5 seconds


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` method to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    var $blockItems = $('.block-item:lt(16)');
    var timer;
    timer = setInterval(function(){
               if(count == 16){ 
                  clearInterval(timer);
                  return;
               }
               $blockItems.eq(count).animate({
                 opacity:0
               },500);
               count++;
            }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Making use of some new features http://jsfiddle.net/7czu4/

```
function HideItems(items, delay) {
    $(items[0]).fadeOut()
        .delay(delay)
        .promise()
        .done(function() {
            items.splice(0, 1);
            if (items.length > 0)
            {
                HideItems(items, delay);    
            }            
    });       
}

var items = $(".item");

HideItems(items, 5000);
```